# How to find every occurrence of a list of values?

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database

I have two tables: `skills` which contains a list of skills, and `job_details` which mentions skills.

I want to find each skill mentioned in `job_details`.

I was using this function in power bi to return the same result

```
Skill_set = CONCATENATEX('Skills',if (search(FIRSTNONBLANK(Skills[Skills],1),'AllData'[jobDetails],,999)<> 999, Skills[Skills])," ")
```

Comment: We can't help you without you sharing your full `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: Also, using `CONCATENATEX` in a query is a sure-fire way to have terrible runtime performance. Please research SARGability.

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL equivalent for the DAX expression you have mentioned ?  Cause this question has SQL tag, please change if its related to PowerBI

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, and if below two tables resemble your setup,

Assume this is a sample `job_details` Table with a skill column

[image]

And this is `Skills` Table listing some skills

[image]

**This would list skills from job_details table that are present in Skills table.**

```
Select skill 
from job_details 
where skill in (select skill from skills)
```

[image]